# Failing to import pandas-datareader, "ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO' from 'pandas.compat'"

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to retrieve data using pandas datareader, but when I try to import it, it will not run generating the error below. I have installed the latest pandas and pandas-datareader through pip.

On a similar question they claimed they solved it by just downgrading to an older version of pandas and pandas-datareader, although when I try to reciprocate this result, it fails to downgrade the two and still continues to have these errors. I had more code earlier and thought that the problem lied within the code, but when I decided to comment out everything I realized that the error occurred during importing as shown below. There is also more to the error message below but I believe I included the important part, as the rest is just the traceback.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'StringIO' from 'pandas.compat' (/Users/roshanamir/Desktop/AI/Pycharm/ATM2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.compat.StringIO` was [removed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/25954) when pandas stopped supporting Python 2 in version 0.25.0.

This has been repaired in pandas datareader and will be released in 0.8.0. For now, download the [latest development version](https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/stable/index.html#install-latest-development-version) where the changes are live.

Comment: Thank you for the information, however, when I install the new release the error message now says `ImportError: cannot import name 'bytes_to_str' from 'pandas.compat'`. Originally part of the traceback stated `from pandas.compat import StringIO, bytes_to_str` so this developmental version seems to have fixed the StringIO part but it seems that the bytes_to_str still remains a problem. Do you have any information as to how to fix it? Thank you in advance. @AddisonLynch